# How to optimize fabricjs performance when rendering large amount of objects?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I've requirement to render a large amount of SVG's as you can see in the screenshot but as the number of objects gets larger and larger the rendering process gets slower. As per the requirement there could be a maximum of 10000 objects and as each of them are SVGs and each SVG have 8 paths therefore there are total 80000 objects. Also each SVG can be coloured independently. So is there any possibility to improve the rendering process somehow ? Please Help.

[image of canvas with 10000 objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCKhR.png)

[image of canvas with 13 objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7UaN.png)

[image of canvas with objects coloured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjBrw.png)

Comment: "each SVG can be coloured independently" in what way? Will you color each of their 8 paths independently or will they stay monochrome? How many unique colors will there be? Why do you need fabric.js for exactly? A solution would be to convert all these SVGs to bitmap, if many various colors, use compositing to make it, otherwise one bitmap per color. If you don't need anything particular from fabric's library, then getting rid of it will definitely improve performances too (don't get me wrong fabric is good at what it does, but perf stress tests is not its best).

Comment: @Kaiido I've added an image to my question to show how the SVG can be coloured. Their 8 paths can be coloured independently. I need fabric.js for ease but can also go with the pure canvas if it really improves the performance. I didn't get the solution of converting all the SVGs to bitmap, could you please explain in detail or send me some article link ?

Comment: @Kaiido please check my last comment